# Filter an array of objects by property JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects.

```
vehicles = [
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "truck", "brand": "F-150" },
  { "name": "Chrysler", "type": "car", "brand": "Sierra" },
  { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
  { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
]
```

How do I filter this by two properties of the objects so there is only one of each? Say name and brand have to be the same?

```
vehicles = [
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "truck", "brand": "F-150" },
  { "name": "Chrysler", "type": "car", "brand": "Sierra" },
  { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
]
```

This isn't working:

```
const filteredVehicles = vehicles.filter((item) => item.name === name & item.brand === brand );
```

Comment: `filter()` is usually a good place to start, perhaps with a `Set` to keep track of what's in or out?

Comment: Does type have to be same?

Comment: @Amolgorithm no

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-on-demand service, where work orders are given and people code for you. Someone may very well answer this question before it gets closed, but it reduces the site's usefulness for everyone when they do.

Comment: @MisterJojo This is a very common thing do in modern web programming, I could not find a clear answer to this question on Stack Overflow, and my question and Daniel's answer will help hundreds or thousands of developers in the upcoming years, so I would say this is a great SO question.

Comment: No wonder your attempt isn't working. What you are trying is wrong on multiple counts:

Comment: (1) The `.filter()` method expects a function that returns `true` if an element should be kept, but you are passing an expression.

Comment: (2) You are using assignment (`=`) instead of comparison (`==` or `===`); this means that you are trying to assign `x.name` to a variable named `name`, and same with `x.brand`. Out of interest, the resultant value of this expression is the value that was assigned.

Comment: (3) `&` is a _bitwise_ AND operator; it sometimes works with numbers as a logical AND, but that is not its purpose. Use the correct `&&` for logical AND comparisons.

Comment: Was that your actual code, or rewritten in a moment of haste or something of the sort? Not shaming; I have sometimes done the same (rewritten instead of copying) and gotten vital parts of the thing wrong.

Comment: @MisterJojo *" it reduces the site's usefulness for everyone when they do"* - does it really though?

Comment: This is a duplicate at best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are libraries that could help with this, but to do it with vanilla JavaScript, filter should be fine.  In the example below filter is used to return elements where there are no elements later in the array that don't match.

```js
const vehicles = [
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "truck", "brand": "F-150" },
  { "name": "Chrysler", "type": "car", "brand": "Sierra" },
  { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
  { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
];

const reduced = vehicles.filter((el, i, ary) => !ary.slice(i + 1)
  .some(x => x.name === el.name && x.brand === el.brand));
console.log(reduced);
```

Feel free to change the expression inside of **some** to match by just the brand.

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce and Object.values to generate a unique key can filter on all the properties.

```js
const vehicles = [
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "truck", "brand": "F-150" },
  { "name": "Chrysler", "type": "car", "brand": "Sierra" },
  { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
  { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
];

const deduped = Object.values(vehicles.reduce((o, v) => {
  o[Object.values(v).join("-")] = v;
  return o;
}, {}));

console.log(deduped);
```

If you only want to filter on specific ones

```js
const vehicles = [
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "truck", "brand": "F-150" },
  { "name": "Chrysler", "type": "car", "brand": "Sierra" },
  { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
  { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
];

const deduped = Object.values(vehicles.reduce((o, v) => {
  o[`${v.name}-${v.brand}`] = v;
  return o;
}, {}));

console.log(deduped);
```

If you want to be dynamic with the properties

```js
const vehicles = [
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
  { "name": "Ford", "type": "truck", "brand": "F-150" },
  { "name": "Chrysler", "type": "car", "brand": "Sierra" },
  { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
  { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
];

const filterOn = ['name', 'brand'];

const deduped = Object.values(vehicles.reduce((o, v) => {
  key = filterOn.map(p => v[p]).join("-");
  o[key] = v; // keeps the last one encountered
  // o[key] = o[key] || v;  // keep just the first one encountered 
  return o;
}, {}));

console.log(deduped);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a generic function that you can supply an array of `props` to. It keeps track of the same props by using a `Set` corresponding to each property, meaning it runs in `O(nm)` time, where `n` is the length of the array and `m` is the number of properties checked.

```js
function filterByProps(arr, props) {
    const sets = props.map((prop) => [prop, new Set()])

    return arr.filter((item) => {
        let numSameProps = 0

        for (const [prop, set] of sets) {
            if (set.has(item[prop])) {
                ++numSameProps
            } else {
                set.add(item[prop])
            }
        }

        return numSameProps < props.length
    })
}

const vehicles = [
    { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
    { "name": "Ford", "type": "SUV", "brand": "Explorer" },
    { "name": "Ford", "type": "truck", "brand": "F-150" },
    { "name": "Chrysler", "type": "car", "brand": "Sierra" },
    { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
    { "name": "GM", "type": "truck", "brand": "Sierra" },
]

for (const propList of [['brand'], ['name', 'brand'], ['name', 'brand', 'type']]) {
    const results = filterByProps(vehicles, propList)
    console.log(new Intl.ListFormat('en-US').format(propList))
    console.log('length', results.length)
    console.log(results)
}
```